# Stress Test Active Directory ESE database with .NET/PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012

Looking for a way to stress test Active Directories ESE Database via PowerShell - so looking for some type of .NET Assembly to load. I've found some information on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg294078(v=exchg.10).aspx but its all low level C/C++.

Anyone attempted this or know any good .NET Libraries that can be loaded into PowerShell. Specifically were attempting to stress "Maximum Allocated EDB Sessions per Thread" settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already saw the ESE DB Managed Reference right?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn375980(v=exchg.10).aspx -- which could be used through PowerShell to target ESE/JET databases.

I don't know if you can do specifically what you asked but if you WOULD be able to do it via methodology native to PowerShell, .NET Managed API would be the way to go.

Otherwise the link you provided could still be used in PowerShell via p/invoke.